Efficient way to initialize a map with 0 in C++
So, I came across this question on Geeks For Geeks:
Count More than n/k Occurences
Question:

Given an array arr of size N and an element k. The task is to find the count of elements in the array that appear more than n/k times.
Example 1:
Input:
N = 8
arr = [3,1,2,2,1,2,3,3]
k = 4

Output:
2

Explanation:
In the given array, 3 and 2 are the only elements that appears more than n/k times.

I approached with a Map, by adding the count of every element in it. The value in arr[] acted as the Key for the Map. The number of occurrences of that Key in arr[] is stored in the corresponding values of the Map. However, I had to first initialize the values in Map with 0, and then run another loop to count the values:
map<int, int> m;
for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
{
     m[arr[i]] = 0;
}

for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
{
     m[arr[i]] += 1;
}

Is there a better or efficient way to do the same thing? Maybe in same loop?
My complete solution (All cases passed, just looking for an efficient way):
//{ Driver Code Starts
// A C++ program to print elements with count more than n/k

#include <iostream>
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

// } Driver Code Ends
class Solution
{
public:
     // Function to find all elements in array that appear more than n/k times.
     int countOccurence(int arr[], int n, int k)
     {
          // Your code here

          int x = n / k, count = 0;
          map<int, int> m;
          for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
          {
               m[arr[i]] = 0;
          }

          for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
          {
               m[arr[i]] += 1;
          }

          map<int, int>::iterator it = m.begin();
          while (it != m.end())
          {
               if ((it->second) > x)
                    count += 1;
          }

          return count;
     }
};

//{ Driver Code Starts.
int main()
{
     int t;
     cin >> t;
     while (t--)
     {
          int n, i;
          cin >> n;

          int arr[n];

          for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
               cin >> arr[i];
          int k;
          cin >> k;
          Solution obj;
          cout << obj.countOccurence(arr, n, k) << endl;
     }
     return 0;
}

// } Driver Code Ends


Second loop is enough, your initialization is superfluous.

Yeah, understanding how a map's operator[] works would be beneficial here. And I would use a std::unordered_map as you don't need the keys to be sorted. And finally std::count_if(). My personal opinion is also that geeks for geeks is an absolute dumpster fire of a site and should be avoided if you actually want to be hired.

Extending my subjective take, all "competitive coding" sites should also be avoided until you have a firm grasp of the language you want to solve problems with and an overall solid foundation of software engineering. I don't mind these sites, as they've helped me cement a few algorithms into my brain. BUT it does need to be shouted that they are awful for learning how to code. You need to already know how to code, and have a good grasp on best practice principles as well. Then, using the sites to cement a few algorithms isn't bad at all.

From a hiring perspective, memorizing algorithms is useful, but not nearly so useful as being able to demonstrate problem-solving skills. Pulling a canned solution out of your head shows me you have a good memory. It shows me nothing about your ability to deal with something you've never seen before.

@user4581301 I concur. It shouldn't be about memorizing a bunch of stuff. It should be about adding to one's list of available tools. So that when a candidate sees something new in an interview, they're better equipped to get the right tools out. Personally, I think interviews should involve reading complex (relative to the position being filled) code and then making changes to it.

@sweenish I haven't tried that one yet, and that's stupid of me considering that tweaking other people's code is at least 50% of the job. Something to add to the interview question list. I'll try to remember to let you know how it turns out.

You are using #include <bits/stdc++.h>, using namespace std; and variable length arrays (VLAs). All three are signs of that you've been learning C++ the wrong way.

@TedLyngmo In this case, it looks like that's provided by the site, and wasn't written by OP directly. But I'm not going to register an account with GFG to find out for sure. I'm just going off of the comments about driver code. Sites like that usually provide a skeleton, and users are typically unable to make changes outside of the Solution class.

@sweenish Oh, yeah, in that case, I'd stay faaar away from that site :-)

Geek for geeks is a very low quality site. Do NOT use it to learn anything. The code you show is full of outdated "C" like constructs. You'd be better of learning C++ from another source first e.g. learncpp.com. Then use sites like cppreference.com and C++ core guidelines to get an idea of how C++ should be used. Also note you don't have to initialize values in a map (just read the documentation on cppreference)

map<int, int> m;...int arr[n]; -- Not even looking at the "bits" header stuff,  both of those lines of code in the same program should be an automatic disqualification if you interviewed for a C++ job.  Having both of these in a program indicates you aren't learning C++.  There is absolutely no way someone who has taken the time to learn C++ would use std::map, but not know to use std::vector<int> arr(n);.  I have seen worse though, where the same program uses vector, but for some reason, goes back to using variable-length arrays.  That definitely is a disqualifier.

Unrelated: The whole counting part could be replaced by return std::count_if(m.begin(), m.end(), [x](auto&& p) { return p.second > x; });

When you use map's operator[] to index an element, it default-initializes that element if the key isn't already in the map yet.  The default initialization for int is 0, so your first loop is redundant.  You can simply remove it.
map<int, int> m;
for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
{
     m[arr[i]] += 1;
}

The reason operator[] works this way is because it returns a reference to an element of the map, and it can't if the element doesn't exist.  So it's forced to create one.

Side note: This is precisely why you cannot use [] on a const map.

Side note:  This the reason you want to use find instead of [].  The find method won't insert a new key.
